# Recombining a .git managed project from two PCs

Tags: git

I've messed up a bit...

I migrated a `git` managed Android Studio project from one PC to another (via a network backup) and continued developing on the new machine. Unfortunately the `.git` folder wasn't included in the migration.

I didn't think I could get the old .git folder back (the old machine wouldn't boot and the .git folder wan't included in the network backup), so I created a new repository in the project on the new machine and all is good there.

I've now managed to get the old .git folder that has all of my old commits in it, but I've already created various new branches and commits on the new machine! Doh!

I'd like to get the full history back on the new machine by merging the two repositories.

If I copy the old .git folder to the new machine and put it alongside the new .git folder but as `.git.old` is there a way to merge the two folders so that the whole branch and commit history is combined under `.git`?

I've read various guides on how to combine projects etc by merging repositories, but I'm concerned that merging two repositories for the same project (albeit sequential in time rather than overlapping) might result in so many conflicts that the merge becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create a new folder `old` (or whatever you want to name it) and copy the `.git` folder of your old project into it. If you want, you can run `git checkout master` to checkout the working tree and view its files. You might also need to run `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Now you have two repositories: `old` with your original git history and `restored` that you restored from the network backup and have continued to develop on. You can add `old` as a remote to `restored` by running the following command from `restored`:

```
git remote add old /path/to/old
git fetch old
```

Now you will see all of the branches from `old` in your repository. You can then move your new history ontop of the old history with `git rebase`:

```
git checkout master
git rebase old/master
```

If you are lucky, this will run cleanly. Most of the time, it won't, though, and you will need to manually edit the files to clean up any merge conflicts.

After you rebase `master` you can also rebase your other branches:

```
git checkout branchName
git rebase master
```